# Overboard and ashore

Tags: meaning

i think it is possible to say 'throw someone overboard' (= meaning that person will thrown into the water)

in a similar sense, can you throw someone ashore (= from the boat to the pier, for example)?

Comment: A captain can evict a passenger

Answer (score 2):

It sounds a bit unusual the context of throwing something ashore but I can't see anything wrong with it.  Things can be washed ashore on the tide, for example, and you can row a boat ashore (especially if your name is [Michael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Row_the_Boat_Ashore)) so that you can get out, so I don't see why you couldn't throw something ashore.

Comment: It would have to be a very lightweight shore to be so easily tossed off like that.

Answer (score 0):

'To throw someone/ something overboard' is idiomatic, 'to throw someone ashore' is a plain English expression that means just that and nothing idiomatic.

You *can* by all means 'throw someone ashore' without violating the rules of grammar – provided of course, the 'someone' will let you do it and get away. It is usually things that get thrown ashore.

The "throw-ashore-anchor" is an example of something that can be thrown ashore.

A heaving line has a weighted end to make it easy to throw ashore or to another
boat.

Answer (score 0):

You can but it sounds painful.

When arriving at my destination, I ask to be **"dropped"** or **"let"** ashore.